# linode.com vs slicehost.com: which fits Java applications better?

Tags: grails, slicehost

I've been searching for a hosting solution for a grails application.

I've read some very good comments on slicehost, but not much about linode.

could some one with the experiences of either of them share your insights please?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Java applications, there should be no difference (unless running it on 32-bit vs. 64-bit matters to you, in which case if you need/want 32-bit you have to go with Linode at the moment).

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746424/linode-or-slicehost for linode-slicehost comparison.

EDIT:
Looks like Slicehost actually now offers 32-bit as well.

Comment: Sadly, the question is removed...:(